# How can we call each id of paragraph of slider which changes each second and limit on their length?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to limit text on my paragraph of slider by calling id and those text are call from database. I use symphony php framework where each slider contain different paragraph.

I can only limit one of first slider paragraph but rest of all paragraph contain came full text.

```
<p id="slider-p">{{ property.description }} </p>

function ellipsify (str) {
     if (str.length > 100) {
         return (str.substring(0, 100) + "...");
     }
    else {
         return str;
     }

};
    var div = document.getElementById('slider-p');
    div.textContent = ellipsify(div.textContent);
```

Result is only for first slider paragraph contain with limit text. *I want for all each slider with limit contain or text.*

Comment: Use CSS instead...

Comment: I removed the 3 other tags, because this questions seems to be about HTML and JavaScript only. If that is not the case, please correct me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your id is not unique. The id attribute must be unique for the document. If you have multiple paragraphs that you want to change, you better use the class attribute:

```
<p class="slider-p">{{ property.description }}</p>
<script>
var divs = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-p');
for(i=0; i<divs.length; i++)
{
    divs[i].textContent = ellipsify(divs[i].textContent);
}
</script>
```

But... wont it just be easier for you to use the CSS text-overflow property? Than you don't have to struggle with the pixel length of your text.

```
p.slider-p {
  white-space: nowrap; 
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Comment: thank you soo much its working and id should be on #slider-p